# Android: onResume in MainActivity not called

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

My app has a **mainactivity** ...

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GameView gameView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gameView = new GameView(this);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(gameView);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        // we dont know yet tho
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        gameView.gameLoopThread.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        gameView.gameLoopThread.onResume();
    }

}
```

and the **gameLoopThread** is

```
 public class GameLoopThread extends Thread {
    private GameView view;
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    static final long FPS = 32;
    private boolean mPaused = false;
    private Object mPauseLock;

    public GameLoopThread(GameView view) {
        this.view = view;
        mPauseLock = new Object(); 
    }

    public void setIsRunning(boolean isRunning) {
        this.isRunning = isRunning;
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
        long startTime;
        long sleepTime;
        while (isRunning) {
            Canvas c = null;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                    view.onDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
            sleepTime = ticksPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            try {
                if (sleepTime > 0)
                    sleep(sleepTime);
                else
                    sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            synchronized (mPauseLock) {
                while (mPaused) {
                    try {
                        mPauseLock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void onPause() {
        synchronized (mPauseLock) {
            mPaused = true;
        }

    }

    public void onResume() {
        synchronized (mPauseLock) {
            mPaused = false;
            mPauseLock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

}
```

anyway the `onResume()` in the mainActivity isn't getting called: I determined this by putting a breakpoint there. so the game pauses when i exit the app, but when i return to the app, it's just a paused screen of the game and it doesn't resume again: I want it to resume when i re-enter the app (using the recent application screen).
Here is the logcat in case there's anything of signifance.

```
12-22 21:39:09.382: I/System.out(10992): Sending WAIT chunk
12-22 21:39:09.402: I/dalvikvm(10992): Debugger is active
12-22 21:39:09.582: I/System.out(10992): Debugger has connected
12-22 21:39:09.592: I/System.out(10992): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-22 21:39:09.792: I/System.out(10992): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-22 21:39:09.985: I/System.out(10992): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-22 21:39:10.185: I/System.out(10992): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-22 21:39:10.392: I/System.out(10992): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-22 21:39:10.592: I/System.out(10992): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-22 21:39:10.795: I/System.out(10992): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-22 21:39:10.994: I/System.out(10992): debugger has settled (1313)
12-22 21:39:12.343: D/dalvikvm(10992): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
12-22 21:42:21.922: W/ActivityThread(11454): Application com.dotdodge is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
```

Comment: @chintankhetiya nothing except for Debugger is active, debugger has connected, waiting for debbuger to settle, and debugger has settled

Comment: @GeoreShg Try to create an instance of `GameView` in your resume method. Write this line `gameView = new GameView(this);` in your onResume method and then check.

Comment: @GrIsHu Didn't work... i believe the problem is that `protected void onResume()` isn't getting called in the first place

Comment: @GeoreShg Does your debugger starts ?

Comment: @GrIsHu Yep... the game works when i debug... i play it for a bit, then click on the home or return button... then i go to the recent applicatons screen, open the application, and all i see is a paused screen of the game

Comment: Please add logging in `onCreate()` of your main activity. See if `onCreate()` is being called when you return to the application via the recent apps screen. If so, you're seeing an Android bug that you'll need to work around.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is a proper solution. But i have once heard about the similar bug. you can try using the following tag in the activity manifest

```
android:noHistory="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement another procedure that's called in your override of OnResume(). The latter is not intended to be called by you, it's a convenience method that tidies up or readies the activity when its state changes to resume. A lot like onStart() through to onDestroy()